# How to get a value from SOAP response using PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to get a value from a SOAP response using PHP. Whatever I did, I couldn't get the value in a variable. Please help.

I am using WordPress's `wp_remote_post()` to submit the form and get the response.

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args);
$xml = $response['body'];
```

Here is the response in SOAP:

```
<soap:envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:body>
        <sendtransactionsactionresponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <sendtransactionsactionresult>113</sendtransactionsactionresult>
        </sendtransactionsactionresponse>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

Here are what I already tried:

```
// Din't work
$value = $xml->body->sendtransactionsactionresponse->sendtransactionsactionresult;

// Din't work
$value = $xml['body']['sendtransactionsactionresponse']['sendtransactionsactionresult'];

//Returned an empty Object
simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Tried a few more things, but none of them worked. I need to get the value of `sendtransactionsactionresult` in a variable to compare. Please help.

Thanks

**EDIT**
`var-dump` of `$response`.

```
 array(5) { ["headers"]=> array(8) { ["connection"]=> string(5) "close" ["date"]=> string(29) "Sat, 26 Sep 2015 18:12:23 GMT" ["server"]=> string(17) "Microsoft-IIS/6.0" ["x-powered-by"]=> string(7) "ASP.NET" ["x-aspnet-version"]=> string(9) "4.0.30319" ["cache-control"]=> string(18) "private, max-age=0" ["content-type"]=> string(35) "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" ["content-length"]=> string(3) "401" } ["body"]=> string(401) "
<soap:envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:body>
<sendtransactionsactionresponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<sendtransactionsactionresult>113</sendtransactionsactionresult>
</sendtransactionsactionresponse>
</soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
" ["response"]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(200) ["message"]=> string(2) "OK" } ["cookies"]=> array(0) { } ["filename"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Are you using SoapClient from PHP?

Comment: No. I am using `wp_remote_post()` to submit the form and receive the response. Like this `$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args); $xml = $response['body'];`

Comment: You whould update your question to include that important detail (:

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: What does it show when you use this: if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
  echo $response->get_error_message(); } ------ After $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args);

Comment: Yes, it does. I think there are no errors as if there were any, I wouldn't get that response code.

Comment: Why didn't you get the response code ? share the `var_dump($response)`

Comment: Try debugging and understand why xml parsing does not works http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php

Comment: @DiegoMariani the `var_dump` result is added to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to WordPress [wp_remote_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post) function documentation the http response result will be in array. 
By to your `var_dump` data, the *body* key exists as a valid XML string.

You have only to **clean your xml** from the *soap:* prefix

```
$response = wp_remote_post( 'http://69.94.141.22/SaveTransactions.asmx', $args);

if(is_wp_error($response))
    return $response->get_error_message();

$xml = str_replace('soap:', '', $response['body']);

$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$result = $obj->body->sendtransactionsactionresponse->sendtransactionsactionresult;

print_r($result);
```

I tried the code, and it works fine ! https://eval.in/440149

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
$foo = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$bar = json_decode(json_encode($foo));
print_r($bar);
```

I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the proper methods to retrieve a valid object from an XML string, here you go:

```
$response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
$xml  = simplexml_load_string($response_body);
$value = $xml->body->sendtransactionsactionresponse->sendtransactionsactionresult;
```