# preg_match returning unlnown modifier

Tags: php, regex

Sorry, I am new to php. I am trying to match a pattern from a string, but whatever I do, I am not getting the matches. I guess I am doing the patterns wrong. Also, sometime I get 'Unknown Modifier' error. Here is the subject string :

```
<soap:envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:body>
<sendtransactionsactionresponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<sendtransactionsactionresult>113</sendtransactionsactionresult>
</sendtransactionsactionresponse>
</soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

I am trying to match the whole `<sendtransactionsactionresult>XXX</sendtransactionsactionresult>` pattern where the XXX is 3 digit numerical characters. Here are the patterns I have tried so far:

```
@<sendtransactionsactionresult>[0-9]<\/sendtransactionsactionresult>@i
/<sendtransactionsactionresult>[0-9]<\/sendtransactionsactionresult>/
@(\<[a-z]\>[0-9]\<\/[a-z]\>)@i
/<[a-z]>[0-9]</[a-z]>/
and many many more..
```

None of them matched that.. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use more appropiate tools than regex? (Xpath, the entire dom extension)?

Comment: Well, I tried to use them all, but nothing helped.. I always get an empty object when I `print_r` the SOAP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799614/how-to-get-a-value-from-soap-response-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quantifiers for your character classes.

`[0-9]` will only match a single digit. To match one or more, you need to use `[0-9]+`.

```
@<sendtransactionsactionresult>[0-9]+</sendtransactionsactionresult>@i
/<sendtransactionsactionresult>[0-9]+<\/sendtransactionsactionresult>/
@(<[a-z]+>[0-9]+</[a-z]+>)@i
/<[a-z]+>[0-9]+<\/[a-z]+>/
```

Also: `/` only need to be escaped if you are also using it as a delimiter. `/...\/.../` vs `@.../...@`.